# Images in a carousel aren't not moving

Tags: javascript, coordinates, carousel, getboundingclientrect

I'am doing a carousel exercise. I can't tell why the content is not moving.
This exercise comes from Javascript.info

https://javascript.info/task/carousel
javascritp.info has proposed a solution, but I want to do it with a alternative way.

I tested with console.log and alert:
The `newPosition` variable seems to change every time when for...of loops runs. But when it comes to assignment of `image.style.left`  to `newPosition`, the images just won't slide. Thanks for your help !

Here is my code :

```js
let container = document.querySelector('#container');
let images = document.querySelectorAll('li');
let nextArrow = document.querySelector('.next')

let move = {
        toRight(e){
    for(let image of images ){
        let newPosition = image.getBoundingClientRect().left - image.clientWidth;
        image.style.left = newPosition + 'px';
    }
}
}

nextArrow.addEventListener('click', move.toRight);
```

```css
.arrow {
  padding: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
}

.arrow:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  position:absolute;
  height: 130px;
  width: 9999px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  left : 5px;
  top:10px;
}

ul img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  display: block; 
  padding:5px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block; 
}

#container{
  position : relative;
  width:430px;
  height:150px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <button class="arrow next">⇨</button>
  
  <div id = 'container'> 
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"></li>
    <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/130"></li>
  </ul>
 <div>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Hermedius/vzouh81d/21/)

Comment: The biggest problem, is that you are using the `left` property, but for that to work, you need to set a `position` property on the `li` element. In your CSS, add `position: relative` to the `ul li` rule. However, your math is still going to be off as your code will only move the first `li` to the left.

Comment: Thank you very much, i think i see the problem.